# Destroy method is not working in spring framework

Tags: java, spring

Edit:
This question is not same as [When does destroy method is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460384/when-is-a-spring-beans-destroy-method-called) because I am properly calling `context.registerShutdownHook` and my bean is getting destory as you can see from the logs. My problem is spring is not calling my method. I have checked this question before asking here.

I am configuring the graceful destroy in my application using spring framework. When I am running the program it is not calling the destory method specified in the bean.xml. Please help me what am I doing wrong.

here is [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Bean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="helloworld" class="com.hello.pojo.HelloWorld" 
          scope="prototype" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

HelloWord.java

```
package com.hello.pojo;

public class HelloWorld {


    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void init(){
        System.out.println("Bean initializating is in progress");
    }

    public void printMessage(){
        System.out.println("Your message: "+getMessage());
    }
    public void destroy(){
        System.out.println("Bean is being destroyed");
    }

}
```

MainApp.java

```
package com.main;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.hello.pojo.HelloWorld;


public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Bean.xml");
        HelloWorld objA = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloworld");
        objA.setMessage("I am Object A");
        objA.printMessage();
        context.registerShutdownHook();
    }

}
```

Output

```
May 27, 2013 11:59:14 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@e9028874: startup date [Mon May 27 23:59:14 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
May 27, 2013 11:59:14 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Bean.xml]
Bean initializating is in progress
Your message: I am Object A
May 27, 2013 11:59:14 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@63390b47: defining beans [helloworld]; root of factory hierarchy
May 27, 2013 11:59:14 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@e9028874: startup date [Mon May 27 23:59:14 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
May 27, 2013 11:59:14 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@63390b47: defining beans [helloworld]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Amendment:
I have tried `close` and `registerShutdownHook()` to close the context and none of them works.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think we can configure method with any name in bean.xml as long as both have a same name. Though I tried with destroy as well and it is not working

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think you mean `destroy`, not `destory` ;)

Comment: @Vulcan I think I mean beer ;)

Comment: @BrendanLong tried the solution but that is not working either.

Comment: Can you try calling context.close() explicitly, to make sure other configuration is correct?

Comment: @gkamal Your solution work I have removed the prototype from the bean and it worked.

Comment: I was having the same issue and found that specifying context.close() resolved my issue. The scope of my bean file was the default 'singleton' and found the `destroy-method` was only run on context.close().

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Destroy method is not called for beans of scope prototype.  This is because the context doesn't keep track of the prototype scope objects (if it does, it will cause a memory leak as spring doesn't know when to dispose it).

Details from the spring documentation.

[Spring reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype)

> There is one quite important thing to be aware of when deploying a
>   bean in the prototype scope, in that the lifecycle of the bean changes
>   slightly. Spring does not manage the complete lifecycle of a prototype
>   bean: the container instantiates, configures, decorates and otherwise
>   assembles a prototype object, hands it to the client and then has no
>   further knowledge of that prototype instance. This means that while
>   initialization lifecycle callback methods will be called on all
>   objects regardless of scope, in the case of prototypes, any configured
>   destruction lifecycle callbacks will not be called.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I removed the prototype and it started working as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much