# beanfactory shutdown in spring to call the destroy() method

Tags: spring

I am using `beanfactory` container to get the bean objects, And I wrote two methods `init()` and `destroy()` to implement some logic at the time of bean initialization and destruction. And I configured in `springconfiguration` file. `init()` is called after dependencies are set, but when `destroy()` method is called, how can I close the `beanfactory`. Somewhere I find when application context is closed then `destroy()` is called, then in case of `beanfactory` when it is called?

Car.java

```
package sringcoreexamples;

public class Car {

    public void start(){
        System.out.println(" car started.....");
    }    
}
```

Travel.java

```
package sringcoreexamples;

public class Travel {

    public Car car;

    public void init(){
        System.out.println("this is bean initialization method.......");
    }

    public void setCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public void travelCheck(){
        car.start();
    }
    public void destroy(){
        System.out.println("this is bean destroy method...............");
    }
}
```

SringCoreExamples.java(Main class)

```
public class SringCoreExamples {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("this is main method............");

        Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");

        BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
        Travel tv=(Travel)factory.getBean("travel");
        tv.travelCheck(); 
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="car" class="sringcoreexamples.Car"/>

<bean id="travel" class="sringcoreexamples.Travel" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy" scope="prototype">

    <property name="car" ref="car"/>

</bean>
```

Comment: Show us your code, please. Read [ask].

Comment: I shared my code please help me

Answer (score 1):

You have to depend on another interface or the implementation.

e.g.

```
((ConfigurableBeanFactory) factory).destroySingletons();
```

if you want to do it automatically, you should upgrade to any `ApplicationContext`, where explicitly any `ConfigurableApplicationContext` have a `registerShutdownHook()` method to automatically deregister beans on JVM exit

In your case either the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` or the `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`

e.g.

```
public class SringCoreExamples {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("this is main method............");

    Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    factory.registerShutdownHooks();
    Travel tv=(Travel)factory.getBean("travel");
    tv.travelCheck(); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your BeanFactory to Any implementation of ApplicationContext as suggested by **[@Niels Bech](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25300771/1487469)**

But Your destroy method will not work until you change scope of your beans because:

Your Beans are of Prototype scope.  **Destroy method is not called for beans of scope prototype.**

Refer following from [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype). Also refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784269/1487469).

> There is one quite important thing to be aware of when deploying a
>   bean in the prototype scope, in that the lifecycle of the bean changes
>   slightly. Spring does not manage the complete lifecycle of a prototype
>   bean: the container instantiates, configures, decorates and otherwise
>   assembles a prototype object, hands it to the client and then has no
>   further knowledge of that prototype instance. This means that while
>   initialization lifecycle callback methods will be called on all
>   objects regardless of scope, in the case of prototypes, any configured
>   destruction lifecycle callbacks will not be called. It is the
>   responsibility of the client code to clean up prototype scoped objects
>   and release any expensive resources that the prototype bean(s) are
>   holding onto. (One possible way to get the Spring container to release
>   resources used by prototype-scoped beans is through the use of a
>   custom bean post-processor which would hold a reference to the beans
>   that need to be cleaned up.)