# When is Spring bean destroyed by default?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

By default Spring beans are singletons, so are beans destroyed if application is shut-down? Or is there any bean time-out?

Comment: Have you read this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460384/when-is-a-spring-beans-destroy-method-called

Comment: the beans will destroy when the appContext is destroyed only. am I right?

Comment: Yes, singleton scoped beans will be destroyed when the application context is shutdown.